# What are the coefficients in the spin sums of $e^- e^+ \rightarrow \mu^- \mu^+$ and how to determine them?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Given the electron and positron spins $s$ and $s'$ and the muon spins being $r$ and $r'$ my question is about the coefficients of the following expression (Peskin and Schroeder page 132):

$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{s} \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{s'}\sum\limits_{r}\sum\limits_{r'} |\mathcal{M}(s,s' \rightarrow r,r')| $

And does the coefficients change if we sum over the initial spin states and average over the final spin states instead the opposite, as the text is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ represents an average over the spin of one of the initial particles (electron and positron).  Going from the left, we the various sums (with $\frac{1}{2}$, if applicable) represent:  an average over the initial electron states ($s$), an average over the initial positron states ($s'$), a sum over the final $\mu^{-}$ states ($r$), and finally a sum over the final $\mu^{+}$ states ($r'$).

If you were summing over initial states and averaging over final states, the factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ would end up in different places, but the expressions would be numerically equal.  However, a sum over initial states and average over final states does not represent a likely physical observable.  You average over the initial states, because the initial polarizations are unknown, and there is a 50/50 chance of each initial electron or positron being in either state.  Over a long run, you will therefore see the average of the scattering rates for initial spin-up states and initial spin-down states.  You simply sum over the final spins because that is what you measure; the total observed cross section is the sum of the cross sections for all the possible outgoing spin states.